# Fast PC and very slow and freezing Windows 10 - no trace in Task Manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, freeze

For last two hours I am experiencing super slow working Windows 10 system. Nothing new installed, it just started happening when browsing internet.

I have fairly fast PC - Threadripper 1950X, 32GB RAM, GTX 1080Ti.

I restarted system multiple times, made more free space on SSD system drive (currently 45GB of 231GB free space), unplugged internet, run CCleaner - no results. It freezes even on windows login screen. I keep monitoring Task Manager, and absolutely no trace of resources usage... CPU 1%, RAM 5,5GB(17%) when idle. Even when dragiing windows on a screen, everything freezes, when starting some heavy software (i.e. photoshop) CPU usage barely moves, and it takes minutes to run the software.

No idea how to proceed from that point, how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried booting your computer into safe mode to see if it behaves the same way? If it seems to behave correctly in safe mode, run an anti-virus program and see if it comes up with anything.

Comment: Try maybe to reset the router (changed settings may need to be redone). Is this also the case for other devices on the local network, and is this Ethernet or WiFi?

Comment: @DrZoo tried safe mode on, still works super slow when dragging windows on screen etc.

Comment: Did you do a virus scan while in safe mode? Normally if it's a virus, safe mode will work fine, but that's not always the case 100% of the time.

Comment: @DrZoo sorry, but avast wont work in safe mode. I can scan computer only in regular boot. I seriously doubt if its a virus, but will do that only to check that one out.

Comment: With Avast I think you can do a boot time scan. There are other programs like Malwarebytes that work in safe mode.

Comment: @DrZoo Im scanning PC now, I will do both Avast and Malwarebytes. One thing I noticed is that CPU runs on full load temps (I know my temperatures, because I monitor them often), but there is nothing showing up in CPU usage in task manager.

Comment: If it's running at full load temps, check your CPU cooler and make sure the fan is running, that it's clear of dust, etc. It could be thermal throttling.

Comment: @DrZoo cooling works fine. Its water cooled, both pump and fans work fine. I have found possible issue. For whatever reason CPU works on 0,5GHz speed instead of 3,4GHz according to task manager. What caused that? How can I bring back full speed of my CPU? Why is it so hot if I'm not using it?

Comment: I'm still unsure if the cooler is working correctly. What you're describing is basically textbook material of an overheating CPU. [Very similar issue here](https://community.amd.com/thread/233450) and [here](https://community.amd.com/thread/230349). Do you have another cooler that you can test with?

Comment: +1 for what @DrZoo is saying. At the very least you need to re-seat the cooling blocks. If you have another cooler to test with, that would also be useful. The low cpu speed could be due to thermal throttling if the temps are too high.

Comment: @DrZoo, you are right, I checked everything and CPU overheats and then drops to 0,5GHz speed. I wasnt expecting that, because entire PC is fairly new. Im cooling it with Enermax Liquitech TR4. I let it cool down and works full speed, then builds up temp pretty fast and drops down its clock. I also noticed weird noises made by pump when I turned it on today. Im going to investigate on what is going on with that cooler. Thankfully its still on warranty...

Comment: Send it in for warranty. With that kind of cooler, I don't think there is much you can do to fix it. If you turn it in and it's been messed with, they will probably void the warranty.